# Meteor js how to upload image on server side?

Tags: meteor

I have created route to upload user image on server and this is my request in server.js file. When i am trying to console filename it does not show anything. 
How i can get file name here?

```
 Router.route('/api/uploadimage/',{where: 'server'})
   .post(function(){

      console.log(this.request.files);

     return false;

  });
```

This is postman request http://prntscr.com/o3svg7 .

Comment: It's telling you that your server did not respond, ie that api request is not getting through

Comment: i have created other api's in same way but they do not have file upload. so is there any issue in my settings or in request i am sending